# Water equivalent of "subterranean"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm trying to say something like "The submarine project something something" to mean an underwater project.

I can't find a concise way of saying it that makes it clear it has nothing to do with the vehicle.

Thoughts?

Comment: subsea project; underwater project.

Comment: The literal analogous term is 'submarine' under the water. But it more easily evokes the underwater ship that it's hard to think of it as meaning just 'under water'. Submarinal? Submediterranean?

Comment: Yes, it's *submarine*.

Comment: .......Aquatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Submarine* fits the bill, although it may remind you of the warship.

***Submarine*** -- [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/submarine)

> (adj.) Existing, occurring, or used under the surface of the sea.
>   *"submarine volcanic activity"*
>
> <sup>synonyms: **undersea**, sub-aquatic, subaqueous</sup>

Comment: Since OP wants to avoid "vessel confusion", your synonyms should do the trick.